# How to align cell content correctly?

Tags: tables

I would like to have in some table  a cell that contains text and graphics wrapped around. The table itself will need several pages. However, `tabularx` aligns the content of the two columns nicely whereas `LTXtable` doesn't. If I'm not mistaken, tabularx cannot split the table onto more than one page. I am using TeXLive under Ubuntu (if that matters). I tried several other packages as well but either the content was aligned (no pagebreak possible) or pagebreak was possible (but the content not in one line). Other packages like `wrapfig` didn't help either.

Is a "compromise" possible?

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,draft=false,fontsize=14pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\input{insbox}
\begin{document}

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mwe_insbox_table.tex}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
    left column & {\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\centering \rule{5cm}{5cm}\end{minipage}} Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. }
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The file `mwe_insbox_table.tex` contains:

```
\begin{longtable}{@{}lX@{}}
left column & {\InsertBoxR{0}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}\centering \rule{5cm}{5cm}\end{minipage}} Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. }
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: `ltablex`? it has features `tabularx` and `longtable`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: `ltablex`doesn't agree with the `insbox` - one of my earlier experiments.

Comment: and what is `insbox`?

Comment: @Zarko: It's a plainTeX macro package which can insert object in a paragraph (left or right). It often works when `wrapfig`  doesn't.

Comment: @Zarko take a look at [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/insbox).

Comment: Could you please give us a picture of what you intend to achieve? I got the `insbox` part, but where and how exactly should the picture be placed?

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for info. if op really need it, than my answer below will not help him, hut if it use only to insert image in table, than my solution work s without this macro. we will see, what op will say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works with `\ltablex` if you add the directive `\keepXColumns` and a negative vertical spacing at the beginning of the `X` cell. I also simplified your code: no `minipage` environment  to type, with `\@minipagetrue` on entering the `X` column:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,draft=false,fontsize=14pt,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage{ltablex, makecell}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\input{insbox}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother

\begin{document}

\keepXColumns
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\compress\arraybackslash}X}
   left column &
   \vspace*{-\baselineskip} \InsertBoxR{0}{{\color{Tomato}\rule{5cm}{5cm}}} Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text. Some silly text.
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Beranrd, catastrophe.  i make extremely silly error. please help me recover your answer!

Comment: @Zarko: There was some mistyping  in my code? I can see no difference.

Comment: no, i intend to delete my answer, but by mistake i do this with yours. sorry. then in panic i didn't  remember how to repair my mistake. excelent answer (+1)

Comment: Keep cool, my friend;o) It was not *that* important, and anyway, I have a copy on my computer.